# How to get and change value of element array in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, indexing

I have 2 arrays:

`$array_1 = [1,2,3,1,2];`

and:

`$array_2 = [0,0,0,0,0];`

I want to change the values of `$array_2`, so it will show if the element in `$array_1` is number 1 or 2 only.

```
foreach($array_1 as $item)
{
    if($item = 1 || $iten == 2)
    { 
        $index = ...;//how to get index of this element
        $array_2[$index] = 1; //I don't sure this syntax is right  
    }
}
```

Output `$array_2` should look like: `$array_2 = [1,1,0,1,1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

// your code goes here
$array_1 = [1,2,3,1,2];

$array_2 = [0,0,0,0,0];
$index = 0;
foreach($array_1 as $item)
{
    if($item == 1 || $item == 2)
    { 
        //how to get index of this emlement
        $array_2[$index] = 1; //I don't sure this syntax is right  
    }
    else
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    $index++;

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_2);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: My above code just is example, $array_1 will be access many times. But this code maybe help me, variable $index will be set when $array_1 be access.

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5 or above, you can do this:
Just pass a array to this function, use a dot notation to handle nested arrays

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
Arr::set($data, 'person.name', 'Calixto');
```

Or you can use this Laravel Helpers:

```
$data = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];
data_set($data, 'products.desk.price', 200, false);
```

For more details look at laravel documentation: 
[Laravel Docs Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-data-fill)

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24066439).

Comment: Sorry, i edited my answer. I hope this can help now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$array_1 = array(1,2,3,1,2);
foreach($array_1 as &$item)
{
  if($item = 1 || $item == 2) {
    $item = 1;
  }
}

echo $array_1;
```

Comment: My above code just is example, $array 1 cannot be changed. Actually, structure's $array_1 and structure's $array_2 are different

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only want to replace items other than 1, 2 to 0, Correct me if I am wrong.

```
$array_3 = array();

foreach ($array_1 as $key => $item)
{
    if($item == 1 || $item == 2)
    { 
        $array_3[$key] = $item;  
    } 
    else 
    {
        $array_3[$key] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP code might do what you intend:

```
<?php
$valid = [1, 2]; // allows you to extend a bit later
$array_1 = [1,2,3,1,2];

$array_2 = array_map(function($var) use ($valid) {
    return in_array($var, $valid) ? 1 : 0; 
}, $array_1);

print_r($array_2); // [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Take a look at the `array_map` function at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php